# search as you type multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

New to elasticsearch .... I am trying to implement search as you type which shows only the top few unique values from a few fields. Consider for example the following documents

### Doc1:

id: 1
name: "computer accessories"
category: "computer"

### Doc2:

id:2
name: "cat food"
category: "cats"

### Doc3:

id: 3
name: "mousepad"
category: "computer"

I want to search both the name and category fields and here is what I want to implement.

When the user types "comp" ... I want to show
computer (category)
computer accessories (name)

So I need to know which field produced the matching result.

Please note. Even though "computer" is the category  of 2 documents ... it should show up only once in the user interface.

when the user types "c" the results should show
cat food (name)
cat (category)
computer (category)
computer accessories (name)

when i type "acc" it should show
computer accessories (name)

Can I implement this using the completion suggester? It appears as if it returns the documents matching .. so how do i know which field matched?

Is there a way to implement this using a method other than the completion suggester? My understanding is that the completion suggester stores the data structure in memory and I am not sure if I can afford huge memory ... I have about 300 million documents to index ..

any pointers will be helpful ...

Comment: When you search using the DSL query, it will give you relevance. You can show the results having the most relevance. I think you can update the behavior of relevance and provide your own implementation (matching the criteria you have mentioned) and can use that. I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: yes .. it does give the relevance (score) .. but it returns documents with same name and category as the top 10 hits ...i want it to return unique names and categories that match my query

Comment: You can try using match phrase type query in which it will match the phrase only. In that way it will won't give you documents with exact name and category as top hits

Comment: Have you tried using multi_match query? See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this post https://dipansaha.wordpress.com/2019/02/14/search-as-you-type-using-elasticsearch-on-multiple-fields/ which uses EdgeNGram to implement search as you type on Multiple fields. You can highlights on the query which will enable you to determine which field matched.